# wp_get_archives, one post missing

Tags: wordpress

i'm trying to built a custom archive page.

there is a dropdownmenu for the year, whichs displays the post count (correctly). but when i pick one year, one post (the newest) is missing.

this is my dropdown

```
<select name="archive-dropdown" onChange='document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;'> 
<option value=""><?php echo esc_attr( __( 'Jahr' ) ); ?></option> 
<?php wp_get_archives( array( 'type' => 'yearly', 'format' => 'option', 'show_post_count' => 1 ) ); ?>
```

and there is my loop

```
<?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
  <div <?php post_class('post-programm'); ?>>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
      <div class="entry-content">
        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

i also tried a query_posts, but in this case i get all the posts, not only for one particular year.

```
<?php query_posts('posts_per_page=-1');
        if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You have a custom filter set somewhere in your theme that is poorly coded that is skipping (offset) the latest post

Comment: any tips how to find this filter?

Comment: It is always (well almost, 99.999% of the time) `pre_get_posts` that is wrongly used. You should search for `pre_get_posts` and check if there is a condition which checks for the main query (`is_main_query()`). This is very important, if it is missing, you have your culprit

Comment: mh. in the fuctions.php is no `pre_get_posts`. the only time i find it is in the query.php from wordpress itself.

Comment: Then you need to start debugging this. Somewhere in a plugin there have to be a filter causing this, or even in your theme ( look for `posts_*` filters ).

Comment: sorry, for beeing dull. the only plugin use is Advanced Custom Fields Pro, even when it's disabled the post are missing.

Comment: Then there is nothing I can help you with further. Switch a bundled theme, if the problem still exist after that, then reinstall Wordpress.

Answer (score -1):

Is your one missing post a custom post type?  wp_get_archives doesn't work with custom posts.

Comment: no, no custom post type.

2015 has 21 posts, 20 are displayed.
2014 has 2 posts, 1 is displayed. 

when i create a new post in 2009 the year 2009 appears in the dropdown, but if i pick it, no post is displayed.